# How can I emulate the eclipse jdt open type action in emacs lsp-java?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp, lsp-ui

In eclipse jdt, there's the open-type command, which opens a window and you start typing the name of a type. While typing, the list of candidates are shown in that window is filtered dynamically and well, you select one of the types in the list to open it.

I tried to find out how to do this in lsp-java, but not very satisfied:

- `M-.` nicely opens the thing under the cursor
- `M-x xref-find-apropos` well, this seems like a candidate, but I most often get `Arithmetic overflow error` back. Had it succeed just once, and also, it doesn't offer completion/filtering etc.

I hope I just miss something.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, thanks for being my rubber duck guys! Just `helm-lsp-workspace-symbols` does exactly what I want.